# Has D&D been translated into Romanian or Serbian?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, translations

I have a cousin in Serbia who is very interested in D&D, but speaks no English. He does speak Romanian and Serbian, and I would love to send him some source books.

Was any edition of the D&D base books ever translated into Romanian or Serbian? Even a bootleg translation would be okay. Links to purchase/download would be ideal, but even a name would be awesome.

Comment: Note (to answerers) that “bootleg” translations, if they exist, are only OK in answers here if they're legal bootlegs, such as if they're a translation of one of the editions that are licensed under the OGL or similar license which allows legal republishing.

Comment: Which edition of D&D? The D&D title represents quite a large number of different incompatible games. Are you looking for the latest (D&D 5e), another edition, just any edition at all..?

Comment: @doppelgreener That was my first thought on seeing tags and title, but the sentence “Was any edition of the D&D base books…” made them make sense. Romanian and Serbian are sufficiently specific and small audiences that it's reasonable to ask for any/all core book translations that exist (if any), especially since all but the latest edition are “finished”.

Comment: I really don't understand why this is having votes to close it as a shopping question

Comment: @Wibbs It superficially resembles one: "I am looking for a game that has *X*." What makes it not a shopping question is that it's not looking for—or even possible to answer with—a recommendation for what to get/play. It's a nuanced difference that is likely easy to miss when evaluating questions like this.

Answer (score 3):

Wizards of the Coast has denied any sort of translation of D&D 5e. There appears to be only offical German, Russian, Spanish and Polish translations of D&D 3.5. There is a thread on a subreddit for /r/Romania which may have some information on D&D in Romanain. I do not see anything about D&D in Serbian though.

/r/Romania thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/Romania/comments/30h1i8/dd_romania/

Comment: There is a French translation of most versions of D&D, at least the latest core books, from version 2 upward for sure.

Comment: 3.0 was translated into more languages than 3.5, so that might be a place to check as well.

Comment: WotC has a bad history with D&D in different languages: The former holder of D&D rights in Germany did hand back his license a year after D&D4 came out. For D&D5 recently a new publisher could be found under the condition that they may adapt anything based the French version by Black Books Editions based on the SRD instead of US pay version.